# Why are scores from sklearn cross_val_score so low?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

Alright, trying to get cross_val_score on 4 different algorithms here. My dataframe looks like this:

```
target   type    post
1      intj    "hello world shdjd"
2      entp    "hello world fddf"
16     estj   "hello world dsd"
4      esfp    "hello world sfs"
1      intj    "hello world ddfd"
```

where the `type` has repeats. Im calculating cross_val score like this:

```
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(result['type'])

train_x, valid_x, train_y, valid_y = model_selection.train_test_split(result['post'], y_encoded, test_size=0.30, random_state=1)

models = {'lr':LogisticRegression(multi_class = 'multinomial', solver = 'newton-cg'),
          'nb':MultinomialNB(alpha = 0.0001),
          'sgd':SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', penalty='l2',alpha=1e-3, random_state=42,
                      max_iter=5, tol=None),
          'rf':RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10)}

for name,clf in models.items():
    pipe = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
                     ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
                     ('clf', clf)])

    res = cross_val_score(pipe,result.post,result.target,cv=10, n_jobs=8)
    print(name,res.mean(),res.std())
```

this works, however the mean values are all around 0.3. The actual accuracy is about 0.98 for all, and 0.7 for logistic regression.

What is wrong here?

EDIT - here is how I know that the mean accuracy of each algorithm is above 0.3 (I do this for each):

```
text_clf3 = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression(multi_class = 'multinomial', solver = 'newton-cg')),
])

text_clf3.fit(result.post, result.target)

predicted3 = text_clf3.predict(docs_test)
print("Logistics Regression: ")
print(np.mean(predicted3 == result.target))
print(metrics.classification_report(result.target, predicted3))

print(confusion_matrix(result.target, predicted3))
print("LR Precision:",precision_score(result.target, predicted3, average='weighted'))
print("LR Recall:",recall_score(result.target, predicted3, average='weighted'))
```

Comment: What do you mean "actual accuracy"? You are printing the average accuracy scores of 4 modeling pipelines.

Comment: @thomaskolasa see my edit

Comment: How many rows do you have? Your edit does not do 10-fold CV, so it has 10x as many examples to learn from.

Comment: @thomaskolasa I have 2000. Honestly Im new to all this - what should I change with the number of folds here?

Comment: Sorry, my comment above was incorrect. Each partition of 10-fold CV trains on 90% of the data.

Comment: @thomaskolasa fair enough. So you dont see anything wrong with the way Im splitting my set and calculating cross_validation ?

Answer (score 0):

In models in your `for` loop, you measure how the models perform on cross validation partitions. In your manual edit, you measure how well you perform on `docs_test`. Normally, you expect your CV scores to be similar to how you perform on an out of sample test set. If you perform considerably better on the test set, perhaps `docs_test` was not randomly created. You may have target leakage. Maybe the model just happens to do well making predictions for that test set.

Comment: Ok. Given these accuracies - svm (0.97), naive bayes (0.95), and random forest  (0.98) logistic regression (0.7) what would normal cross_validation means and stds look like?

Comment: In your for loop, How well does `pipe.predict(docs_test)` perform on `docs_test`? That should give you the same result as when you manually made predictions on `docs_test`.